# Onesignal Java Error sending tags on onesignal-java-api but works in Rest

Tags: java, onesignal

im trying to implement the consume of tags on my app

it works when i do from rest way like this from postman

url: https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications

```
{
"app_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"contents": {
    "en": "Message",
    "es": " Message"
},
"name": "INTERNAL_CAMPAIGN_NAME",
"filters": [
    {"field": "tag", "key": "email", "relation": "=", "value": "AAAAA@AAAAA.com"}
],
"channel_for_external_user_ids": "push"
```

}

but when i try using java client from https://github.com/OneSignal/onesignal-java-api

```
HashMap<String, String> contents= new HashMap<>();
    contents.put("contents", "this is the value of contents");
    contents.put("tags","{ key: \"email\", relation: =, value: \"AAAAAA@AAAAA.com\" }");

Notification notification = new Notification();
notification.setAppId(APP_KEY);
notification.setIsChrome(true);
notification.setIsAnyWeb(true);

StringMap contentStringMap = new StringMap();
contentStringMap.en(contents.get("contents"));
notification.setContents(contentStringMap);

notification.setTag(contents.get("tags"));
```

it shows error like this

HTTP response code: 400
HTTP response body: {"errors":["You must include which players, segments, or tags you wish to send this notification to."]}

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figure out i need to create a segment for uses tags and filters
so for that I create a fork https://github.com/Qleoz12/onesignal-java-api from the original project https://github.com/OneSignal/onesignal-java-api im just add filters to [notification.java](https://github.com/OneSignal/onesignal-java-api/commit/9132fb276fba3c94225d9e6449442f9e7c57674e#diff-d81761eeee59ac59ec524937370f4a6fa923dfdee7fd05c32e5302467fda82be)

and I check the java client now creates the body similar and works like postman as expected